# Can a preceding vehicle mean a vehicle ahead?

Tags: adjectives

> When driving, you should keep a certain distance from a vehicle ahead of you (or in front of you)

I would like to use "a preceding vehicle" instead of "a vehicle ahead of you" because "a vehicle ahead of you" is longer.  Is it acceptable?

Comment: In this case, I like the longer version better. The phrase _preceding vehicle_ is simply not idiomatic (at least, not in AmE).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preceding+vehicle%2C+vehicle+in+front%2C+vehicle+ahead%2C+front+vehicle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpreceding%20vehicle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvehicle%20in%20front%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvehicle%20ahead%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfront%20vehicle%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @J.R. Similarly in Britain. One never hears "preceding vehicle" used, though it is clear what it means. Usual terms are "the vehicle in front", or "the vehicle ahead".

Comment: Here is the term used in The Washington Post: "A more important issue seems to be whether each person starts out promptly when the light turns green and keeps up with **the preceding car** through the intersection." Here is The L.A. Times: "Shake your fist at God and the old lady in front of you who allows wide gaps between her and **the preceding car**" articles.latimes.com/2004/mar/29/entertainment/et-martinez29 You can find this use of the term all over the place in North American English.  Even if it's not "common," it's certainly "acceptable."

Comment: @rama9: You're only going to get opinions on this question unless you provide a context for the statement you're trying to make, and full example sentence.

Comment: I should have said that it is 'seldom' heard in the UK, not 'never' heard. If a serious newspaper like the Washington Post would use it, a similar organ in Britain might equally employ 'preceding' in this formal way. Whilst in everyday conversation people don't talk about 'the preceding' vehicle, I see no reason why, in a formal document such as an insurance report, or a Dept of Transport discussion paper, 'preceding vehicle' might not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not an idiomatic or acceptable substitute for "the car ahead", for "a preceding vehicle" does not mean "the car in front of you *as seen from your location behind it*".

A car can precede yours through a toll gate, say. It goes through *sooner* than yours does. To **precede** is a spatio-temporal absolute.

P.S. "A preceding vehicle" lacks *origo*, or "deictic center".  The idiomatic deictic meaning of **the car ahead** places the driver at the deictic center. "A preceding vehicle" does not do this.  Although "a preceding vehicle" would be understood to refer to a vehicle ahead of the driver's vehicle, the reference is not made from the driver's perspective but from a neutral, objective perspective.

"Pay attention that you don't get too close to *the preceding vehicle*" is a space oddity.  A parent wouldn't tell a teen learning to drive "Don't get too close to the preceding vehicle".  "The preceding vehicle" is the sort of thing we find on accident reports written by the police.

Comment: While a car can precede you through a toll gate, "the preceding car" would still mean the car that directly preceded you, or came most immediately before you.  Similarly, on the road, "the preceding car" would be the one that comes most immediately before you on the road.  In the example given, it is the car directly preceding you on the road that you want to "keep a certain distance from"

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime: Please note the phrase OP wants to use: "a preceding vehicle".  That is not idiomatic, and it does not mean "the car ahead". Also, please note "as seen from you location behind it".

Comment: to say that this usage "is not correct or acceptable," is an overstatement at least, and outright false at most.  It's perfectly acceptable, it is only a matter of taste and popularity of the term in this context.  *Deixsis* has no bearing on the use of **preceding** in this context. As for article choice, the OP could change the phrase to "**the** preceding vehicle" and that would be enough to denote the car moving *immediately* before the driver -- ahead of them.  "Preceding" and "ahead of" are in fact synonyms: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/preceding?s=t

Comment: I've changed it  to read "not an idiomatic or acceptable substitute for **the car ahead**.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusions, but rather than argue further I'll let others take a look.

Comment: Assuming they understand the point I'm trying to make, and don't just cite attestations of "the preceding vehicle"...

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is acceptable.  There are many [technical articles](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218127415400386?journalCode=ijbc) and patent applications that use "preceding vehicles" when discussing technology for detecting cars ahead of a principal car.

Another option would be to remove "of you" and write:

> When driving, you should keep a certain distance from **the** vehicle **ahead.**

Comment: Interesting.  TRomano says no, but apparently this use of "preceding" has become a thing since the advent of self-driving technology.  However the ELL student should be aware this isn't common usage (yet) and while it would be appropriate in a technical article, it might not make sense in casual conversation.

Comment: @Andrew please see my comment on TRomano's answer.  To reiterate, "the preceding car" relative to a driver is the one that comes "immediately before" it, whether through a toll gate or on the road.  While it's not a common term in reference to cars, it would make sense to me in casual conversation as a native English speaker.

Comment: You are missing the point I made about *deixis*.  Those technical articles are using the term "a preceding vehicle" as I indicated, as spatio-temporal absolutes, which is not at all how we use the phrase "the car ahead".

Comment: Moreover, the title of that technical article is written by a non-native speaker (note "on curve [sic] road")

Comment: @TRomano The examples are not limited to technical articles.  Here is the term used in *The Washington Post*:  "A more important issue seems to be whether each person starts out promptly when the light turns green and keeps up with **the preceding car** through the intersection." Here is The L.A. Times: "Shake your fist at God and the old lady in front of you who allows wide gaps between her and the preceding car"
     http://articles.latimes.com/2004/mar/29/entertainment/et-martinez29  You can find this use of the term all over the place.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime. Again, you are missing my point about *deixis*.   "The preceding car" has no "origo" and for that reason it is not an idiomatic substitute for "the car ahead".  The idiomatic deictic meaning of "the car ahead"  makes "of you" unnecessary.

Comment: @TRomano The *origo* is the car the driver is in, as implied by the subject "you" in the example sentence. Apart from that, please explain in more detail what your point is about *deixis.*  In response to your last sentence, that's actually something I wrote in my answer.  See my last sentence and example.

Comment: I've attached a P.S. to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the word preceding as an adjective preceding something like a vehicle to mean front or ahead, but that's far less common.  You usually use the phrase "in front" or "ahead" as follows:

".......keep a certain distance from the vehicle in front".

"....... keep a certain distance from the vehicle ahead".

You can  also use the front as an adjective as follows, but it's not so commin.

"....... keep a certain distance from the front vehicle".

BTW, you can also say  "....keep your distance from the vehicle in front/ahead".